# How to create an AddCoins application?

Tags: java, methods

that prompts the user for the number of pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters, and then displays their total dollar amount. The application should include a getDollarAmount() method that has 4 int parameters corresponding to the number of pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters and returns a String that corresponds to the dollar value of the coins.

the application output should look similar to:

Enter you total coins:

Quarters:3
Dimes:2
Nickels:1
Pennies:8

Total: $1.08

and this is my attempt:

```
package ch7e5;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch7E5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1, p, d, n, t;
        double Q1, D1, N1, P1;


        System.out.println("Enter your total coins:");
        System.out.print("Quarters:");
        n1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Dimes:");
        d = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Nickles:");
        n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Pennies:");
        p = input.nextInt();
        double Q1 = (pennies * 0.01);

    private static double calctotal(double Q1, double D1, double P1, double N1) {
        double dbltotal;
        dbltotal = (Q1 + D1 + P1 + N1);
        return dbltotal;
    }
}
```

This is my 2nd attempt with the help of your comments:

```
package chapter7ex5;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Chapter7ex5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your total coins:");

    System.out.print("Quarters:");
    int Q1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Dimes:");
    int D1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Nickles:");
    int N1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Pennies:");
    int P1 = input.nextInt();



    }
public static double calctotal(int Q1, int D1, int N1, int P1) {
    double total;
    total=((0.25 * Q1) + (0.1 * D1) + (0.05 * N1) + (0.01 * P1));
    return (total);

}}
```

I think my attempts are over:

```
package chapter7ex5;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Chapter7ex5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your total coins:");

    System.out.print("Quarters:");
    int Q1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Dimes:");
    int D1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Nickles:");
    int N1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Pennies:");
    int P1 = input.nextInt();

  DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.##");
    System.out.println("Total:"+fmt.format(calctotal(Q1, D1, N1,
            P1)));

    }
public static double calctotal(int Q1, int D1, int N1, int P1) {
    double total;
    total=((0.25 * Q1) + (0.1 * D1) + (0.05 * N1) + (0.01 * P1));
    return (total);

}}
```

Comment: Add your code to the question instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one quarter is usually worth `0.25`. A dime is worth ten cents and so on. Also, you seem to have swapped nickels and pennies. And your numbers will always be `int`. Finally, a method does not go within the body of another method. So, move `calctotal` outside of `main()` and calculate the values of your coins with something like

```
private static double calctotal(int Q1, int D1, int N1, int P1) {
    return ((0.25 * Q1) + (0.1 * D1) + (0.05 * N1) + (0.01 * P1));
}
```

You should probably call `flush()` if you use `System.out.print()`, it isn't automatic without a newline. Then you could use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format your calculate total like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your total coins:");
    System.out.print("Quarters:");
    System.out.flush();
    int quarters = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Dimes:");
    System.out.flush();
    int dimes = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Nickles:");
    System.out.flush();
    int nickels = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Pennies:");
    System.out.flush();
    int pennies = input.nextInt();
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.##");
    System.out.println(fmt.format(calctotal(quarters, dimes, nickels,
            pennies)));
}
```

Comment: Its running properly, except it doesnt output the total. How would you do this?

Comment: @milli I would use the last two statements in my `main()` method above.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry if this seems like a silly question but this is the first time doing computer science and using loops, so im not very good with terms. Oh like this!! @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @milli `System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("$#,###.##").format(calctotal(quarters, dimes, nickels,
            pennies)));`

Answer (score 0):

Not bad. Something I noticed is that you only calculate the double value of the pennies, not the quarters, dimes, and nickels. That conversion should also be done inside your function:

```
private static double calcTotal(int pennies, int nickels, int dimes, int quarters)
{
    return ((pennies * 0.01) + (nickels * 0.05) + (dimes * 0.10) + (quarters * 0.25));
}
```

Outputting the amount is easy too, just use something like this in your main function:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",calcTotal(p, n, d, q));
```

The doubles have have created in your main aren't necessary, and you should change how you get your amounts of coins to:

```
System.out.print("Quarters: ");
q = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```